# How to get the date when calendar rendering date cells

Tags: fullcalendar

I've a situation where I need to get the date to attach in each event url (For event url's I'm adding the href attr using jquery) query string but after checking the docs I found both `eventClick` and `eventRender` do not returns the date of cell upon which event is showing.

I tried google for it and found tricky solutions using the `eventClick` callback and use page X and Y and then get the nearest element which holds the data attribute with date for the particular cell date but

```
eventClick:function(event,jsEvent,view){
var clickedDate = $.nearest({x: jsEvent.pageX, y: jsEvent.pageY}, '.fc-day').attr('data-date');
alert(clickedDate);
}
```

But this solutions fails when I've multiple event on the same date cell and more events will be shown in a popup.

 

**Note : [$.nearest](https://github.com/gilmoreorless/jquery-nearest/) is the jquery plugin to find the nearest element from given X,Y postions**

Note : I'm using v2

Comment: Can't you just use `event.start`?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev In case of repeated events event.start is same for all instances

Answer (score 0):

Does this work sufficiently well for you?

http://jsfiddle.net/3E8nk/531/

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultDate: '2014-06-12',
    editable: true,
    eventRender: function(event, element, view) {

        var start = event.start.clone().startOf('day');
        var end = event.end ? event.end.clone().endOf('day') : start.clone().endOf('day');

        //Known bug: We get all "touching" events and not just necessarily events on the day we clicked

        var events = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');

        var touchingEvents = events.filter(function(event) {
            var
                eventStartWithin = event.start.isWithin(start, end),
                eventEndWithin = event.end ? event.end.isWithin(start, end) : false;
            return eventStartWithin || eventEndWithin;
        });

        console.log(touchingEvents);

    },
    events: [
        {
            title: 'All Day Event',
            start: '2014-06-01'
        },
        {
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: '2014-06-07',
            end: '2014-06-10'
        },
        {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2014-06-09T16:00:00'
        },
        {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2014-06-16T16:00:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: '2014-06-12T10:30:00',
            end: '2014-06-12T12:30:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Lunch',
            start: '2014-06-12T12:00:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Birthday Party',
            start: '2014-06-13T07:00:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Click for Google',
            url: 'http://google.com/',
            start: '2014-06-28'
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: I'm thinking of the loop which render fullcalendar it can give me each date and thats I need to append to my events.

Comment: Ye, you can rewrite the source to tell you this info too. Is that what you mean? It wouldn't be so hard I think

Comment: I appreciate your help !! I managed it from server side.. thanks for your help anyway.