# Apply minTime and maxTime specific to current week

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm working in week mode and I want to limit visible time range to the earliest event on the week and the latest event on the week.

I guess the right way to solve the problem is to manually filter events that are visible in current week, find the mininum and maximum time and set them to minTime and maxTime property. The problem is that I don't see weekChanged callback (or something like that) which seems a right place to recalculate minTime and maxTime.

Comment: Look at [viewRender](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewRender/). Sounds like you know what to do

Comment: @RichardHermanson, seems close to what I need. But seems like there is no way to retrieve events for current date-range.

Comment: You could use [eventRender](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) for that I guess or you could use [getView](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/View_Object/) and then filter [clientEvents](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/clientEvents/) using the interval start and end. If you go for the latter then [maybe this code will help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26278724/how-to-get-the-date-when-calendar-rendering-date-cells/26287368#26287368)

Comment: @RichardHermanson, seems like a right thing to do. Could be some problems with timezones though.

Comment: So you want this but dynamically? http://jsfiddle.net/3E8nk/542/

Comment: @RichardHermanson, yeah

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was a lot more work than I expected, hope it works well enough for you. I'm basically doing what I suggested in the comments above.

**Edit:**
Changed code to improve performance so we don't have to wait for all of the calendar to render before finding out that we need to start all over again.

Note that to do this more effectively we would either have to implement a new callback because none of the existing ones seem to have clientEvents set already or calculate times from the events beforehand (which could get messy in case of timezones).

http://jsfiddle.net/3E8nk/555/

```
(function(c) {

    var startedViewRender = true;

    function greaterTime(first, second) {
        //Assuming dates are the same year
        if (first.clone().dayOfYear(0).isBefore(second.clone().dayOfYear(0)))
            return second;
        else
            return first;
    }

    var calendarOptions = {
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'agendaWeek'
        },
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        minTime: '00:00:00',
        maxTime: '24:00:00',
        defaultDate: '2014-06-12',
        defaultTimedEventDuration: '02:00:00',
        editable: true,
        events: [{
            title: 'All Day Event',
            start: '2014-06-01'
        }, {
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: '2014-06-07',
            end: '2014-06-10'
        }, {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2014-06-09T16:00:00'
        }, {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2014-06-16T16:00:00'
        }, {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: '2014-06-12T10:30:00',
            end: '2014-06-12T12:30:00'
        }, {
            title: 'Lunch',
            start: '2014-06-12T12:00:00'
        }, {
            title: 'Birthday Party',
            start: '2014-06-13T07:00:00'
        }, {
            title: 'Click for Google',
            url: 'http://google.com/',
            start: '2014-06-28'
        }],
        viewRender: function(view) {
            startedViewRender = true;
        },
        eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
            if (!startedViewRender)
                return;
            else
                startedViewRender = false;

            if (view.name !== 'agendaWeek') {
                console.log('not agendaWeek');
                return;
            }

            var events = c.fullCalendar('clientEvents');

            if (events.length === 0) {
                console.log('no events at all');
                //Set to default times?
                return;
            }

            var visibleAndNotAllDayEvents = events.filter(function(event) {
                //end not necessarily defined
                var endIsWithin = event.end ? event.end.isWithin(view.start, view.end) : false;
                return !event.allDay && (event.start.isWithin(view.start, view.end) || endIsWithin);
            });

            if (visibleAndNotAllDayEvents.length === 0) {
                console.log('no visible not all day events');
                //Set to default times?
                return;
            }

            var earliest = visibleAndNotAllDayEvents.reduce(function(previousValue, event) {
                return greaterTime(previousValue, event.start).isSame(previousValue) ? event.start : previousValue;
            }, moment('23:59:59', 'HH:mm:ss'));

            var latest = visibleAndNotAllDayEvents.reduce(function(previousValue, event) {
                var end = event.end ? event.end.clone() : event.start.clone().add(moment(calendarOptions.defaultTimedEventDuration, 'HH:mm:ss'));

                return greaterTime(previousValue, end);
            }, moment('00:00:00', 'HH:mm:ss'));

            if (calendarOptions.minTime !== earliest.format('HH:mm:ss') || calendarOptions.maxTime !== latest.format('HH:mm:ss')) {
                //Reinitialize the whole thing

                var currentDate = c.fullCalendar('getDate');

                c.fullCalendar('destroy');
                c.fullCalendar($.extend(calendarOptions, {
                    defaultDate: currentDate,
                    minTime: earliest.format('HH:mm:ss'),
                    maxTime: latest.format('HH:mm:ss')
                }));
            }

        }
    };

    c.fullCalendar(calendarOptions);

})($('#calendar'));
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you. up up up!!

Answer (score 5):

You can do that by using [`eventAfterAllRender`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterAllRender/), which is executed after all events have been rendered

```
eventAfterAllRender: function(view) {
    var evts = $("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'clientEvents'),
        minTime = moment("2014-01-01 23:59:59").format("HH:mm:ss"),
        maxTime = moment("2014-01-01 00:00:00").format("HH:mm:ss"),
        currentDate = view.calendar.getDate(),
        currentMinTime = view.calendar.options.minTime,
        currentMaxTime = view.calendar.options.maxTime;

    // lets calculate minTime and maxTime based on the week events
    // if this event's minTime is 'before' than the minTime, set this as the minTime
    for(var i in evts) {
        minTime = timeDiff(minTime, evts[i].start.format("HH:mm:ss"), true);
        maxTime = timeDiff(maxTime, evts[i].end.format("HH:mm:ss"), false);
    }

    // If minTime or maxTime don't match, recreate fullcalendar
    // This is a pain in the ass : \
    // We have to destroy and apply fullcalendar so this can work.
    if (minTime != currentMinTime || maxTime != currentMaxTime) {
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar('destroy');
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar(
            $.extend(fcOpts, {
                defaultDate: currentDate,
                minTime: minTime,
                maxTime: maxTime
            })
        );
    }
}
```

You will have to have a function to calculate which time is the lattest or earliest:

```
function timeDiff(time1, time2, getMin) {
    var d1 = new Date('2014-01-01 ' + time1),
        d2 = new Date('2014-01-01 ' + time2);

    if (getMin) {
        return d1.getTime(d1) - d2.getTime(d2) < 0 ? time1 : time2;
    } else {
        return d1.getTime(d1) - d2.getTime(d2) > 0 ? time1 : time2;
    }
}
```

See [**the following JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/c9cbotL1/) for a working example.

Comment: I chose not to do this because it happens after render but clientEvents aren't available yet at viewRender either. Know of any earlier callback that has clientEvents set?

Comment: I haven't found any callback that allows that. I guess we could extend FullCalendar and add a custom callback (like you state in your edit). Most likely we would have to tweak the source code which is never a good thing..